# Trouble with OCaml nested if

Tags: if-statement, functional-programming, ocaml, nested-if

With my original code I kept getting `Error: Parse error: [expr level ;] expected after "in" (in [expr])` on the line `let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in`

Original:

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
     num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in

    let numDigits = String.length(string_of_int num) - 1 in

    if num < 0 then
      let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in
    else
      let numDigits = numDigits + 0 in

    let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
    temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
```

With variations of:

```
if num < 0 then
   let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in;
else
   let numDigits = numDigits + 0 in;
```

---

```
if num < 0 then
   let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in
else begin
   let numDigits = numDigits + 0 in end
```

I revised the code and now it works, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with nested if and less redundancy.

Revised:

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in

    let numDigits = String.length(string_of_int num) - 1 in

    if num < 0 then
      let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in
      let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
      temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
    else
      let numDigits = numDigits + 0 in
      let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
      temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
```

Comment: Might this be more appropriate to ask on [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocaml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Hunan Rostomyan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139096/trouble-with-ocaml-nested-if/139097#139097)

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in

    let numDigits = String.length(string_of_int num) - 1 in

    let numDigits = numDigits - (if num < 0 then 1 else 0) in
    let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
    temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
```